# MySQL UTF8 Conversion - Why dump the database?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm needing to convert my MySQL database from `latin1_sweedish_ci` to `utf8`, it looks like `utf8_bin` is my ideal option.  I keep reading that some people have exported their databases and recreated them.  Is this really necessary?  Can't I just run queries to convert the data?

I read that one guy when installing MySQL 5, specified `UTF-8` during MySQL compiling...

Comment: Why not `ci`, but `bin`?

Comment: From what I've read, `A = Ä` will return true if I don't use `utf8_bin` in MySQL comparisons.  A != Ä, so I don't want it to return true.

Comment: Sure, you can use [`CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: it is not what he needs

Comment: @Webnet `A = Ä` in utf8_general_ci, but `A != Ä` in utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 1):

You have to export the database and convert them. Setting database, table, and row encodings change how they will be operated on *in the future*, but do not convert the data that has already been stored.

There is no database encoding swap free lunch.

In MySQL 5, you have to reset all the character encodings for the db, tables, and columns, AND THEN re-import the data. The [wordpress guide to changing char sets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets) is a good step-by-step resource to do this.

I would suggest reading the Wordpress how-to as the steps are well explained and clear, but the highlights are:

Set DB char set:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then set existing tables encodings:

```
ALTER TABLE db_table CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then dump w/ one encoding, re-import with another

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password --default-character-set=latin1_swedish_ci dbname > dump.sql

mysql --user=username --password=password --default-character-set=utf8 dbname < dump.sql
```

Note that if you do not want to dump & reload the whole database, you can perform the change column-by-column by converting each text column to the equivalent blob type, and then converting it back to a text column w/ the desired encoding as described in the Wordpress guide's [convert columns to blob and back](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets#Converting_columns_to_blob.2C_then_back_to_original_format_with_new_charset).

Comment: `iconv` is not necessary here. I'd even say it is evil in this case. You've given a link to WP guide, which doesn't use `iconv` at all too ;-) `AND THEN convert the data` --- **NO**, the data should be left as-is.

Comment: @zerkms, thanks for the reality check. I had pulled the iconv from an old script I had for previous MySQLs. Updated answer with `mysqldump` steps.

Comment: that's much better, +1 then ;-)

Comment: @Shelhamer Wouldn't it be better to dump the database before the ALTER TABLE statements?

Comment: @Andreas Krueger, sorry that was my fingers’ answer and not my brain. Both `ALTER` statements are supposed to set the encoding to be used with the db in future operations, but do not change the data already stored. Correct steps are 1) ALTER .. CHARACTER SET 2) dump 3) import w/ new character setting

Comment: I see... so you change the columns, then go through and update the data by dumping/reloading

Comment: Could I just alter each column separately instead of a dump/reload ?

Comment: You cannot simply ALTER TABLE...CHANGE each column directly because characters will be mangled, hence the suggestion to dump/reload. However, you can do it column by column in two steps if you desire as described in the Wordpress guide's [converting columns to blob and back](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets#Converting_columns_to_blob.2C_then_back_to_original_format_with_new_charset)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to dump & reload. You can have MySQL transcode the values, but you have to issue an ALTER for **each and every column that contains text data**. Pretty annoying, you'd have to write a script to generate it ! And after that, you still need to change all the default values.

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` CHANGE `mycolumn` `mycolumn` 
TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: So even after running that query I'd have to have a script go through and encode all the data?  Is it possible to encode the data in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

does all the conversion for me, including columns, what I needed to do though was to write this for every table in the database.